# tensor product of matrices

Tags: tensor-products

Hello, all!
Could somebody draw a proof-sketch of next expression from tensor algebra on matrices over finite fields:
determinant of tensor product $A~ \times ~B$ of $n \times n$-matrix $A$ over finite field $GF(q)$ on $m \times m$-matrix $B$ over finite field $GF(q)$ is $\det(A)^m \cdot \det(B)^n$.

Please, give me a link or reference if it is online or in some book.
Thank you.

Comment: Would that there was a wikipedia equivalent to lmgtfy.com...

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product

Comment: Hint: $A\otimes B = \left(A\otimes I_m\right)\circ \left(I_n\otimes B\right)$.

Comment: Excuse me, please. I am sorry, but I forgot to write that I need this fact satisfaction in case of finite field

Comment: The argument given on the Wikipedia is the standard ugly one.

Comment: spk: It doesn't matter which field or ring you are in (as long as it is commutative).

Comment: Could you explain in more details, please. In Wikipedia it was wroten that main idea is to consider a matrix spectrum. In case of finite fields spectrum do not existed.

Comment: But in a field extension it does.

Comment: Spectra of matrices are well behaved in any algebraically closed field, and it does not matter whether you compute the determinants in a given field or in its algebraic closure.

Comment: Thank you. This is good stuff to think about. But what should I do with singular values over finite field if I want to prove statement about rank of matrix tensor product?

Comment: Better don't use singular values for this. Note that for two linear maps $f:A\to C$ and $g:B\to D$ between vector spaces $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$, the image $\left(f\otimes g\right)\left(A\otimes B\right)$ is the same as the image of the canonical map $f\left(A\right)\otimes g\left(B\right)\to C\otimes D$ (induced by the injections $f\left(A\right)\to C$ and $g\left(B\right)\to D$). Now notice that the tensor product of two injective maps is injective (here you use that you are over a field and not an arbitrary commutative ring!).

Comment: @Emil: yes, but one should beware of facts like: $\mathrm{det}_{\mathbb{R}}(...)=|\mathrm{det}_{\mathbb{C}}(...)|^2$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Darij's first comment could be made into an answer as follows.

Darij advised to write

$$A \otimes B = (A \circ I_n) \otimes (I_m \circ B) = (A \otimes I_m) \circ (I_n \otimes B)$$

where the second equation follows from functoriality of the tensor product. Here both $A \otimes I_m$ and $I_n \otimes B$ are square matrices of size $m n \times m n$. Since the determinant from such matrices to the scalar field is a monoid homomorphism, the determinant of the last expression is

$$\det(A \otimes I_m) \det(I_n \otimes B)$$

so we are left to determine the two determinants above. Since these are similar, we do the first. We may express an $m$-dimensional vector space $k^m$ as a direct sum of 1-dimensional vector spaces, so

$$A \otimes I_{k^m} = A \otimes (I_k \oplus \ldots \oplus I_k) = (A \otimes I_k) \oplus \ldots \oplus (A \otimes I_k)$$

because tensor products preserve direct sums. This is just $A \oplus \ldots \oplus A$. This matrix consists of $m$ blocks of $A$, so its determinant is $\det(A)^m$, and we are done.

Comment: Thank you for your assistance. It is what I really need with my question